# XButton negative feedback type in Facebook Insights stats

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

There should be four types of posts negative feedback according to docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#negative_feedback but we are often getting one more feedback type called "xbutton". Does anyone know what it means? [image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try to ask these types of questions here .. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Upon a bit of research, another developer and I are almost positive that the "xbutton" value refers to the number of times a user clicked the "x" button next to a post, but didn't necessarily go through with actually taking an action listed on the dropdown (such as hiding the post or hiding all posts from that user).

Notice that all "xbutton" values are **equal to or higher than** the amount of "hide" and "hide_all" counts (indicating that they were required to hit the "xbutton" before taking another action).

Perhaps this is Facebook's way of recording the *intent* of hiding a post.

Answer (score 0):

For all of those who are still looking for an answer, recently I asked facebook support the same question and documentation was updated with:

> xbutton_clicks - Deprecated. This is no longer logged

source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/insights#negative_feedback